# Convert Google Sheets "sort" formula with embedded VLOOKUP into equivalent app script

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup

I have a Google Sheets "sort" formula that I want to convert into an app script equivalent so that I can apply the sorting to a set of rows whenever I click a button on the page.  The difficult part is that the sort formula has an embedded VLOOKUP that is used to convert a string column into a number.  Here is the formula:

`=sort(D2:J,I2:I,TRUE,D2:D,TRUE,VLOOKUP(E2:E,'Frequency'!A:B,2,FALSE),TRUE,H2:H,TRUE,G2:G,TRUE)`

The sort creates the output perfectly, but it does not affect the source rows.  I would like the script to reorder the source rows exactly as the sort formula does.  How can I accomplish this?

| Name | Task | Type | Frequency | Room |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Task 1 | Routine | Weekly | 203a |
| Jane | Task 2 | Security | Daily | 102 |

I have tried the usual Google searches for relevant results.  The closest I could come was this:

```
`spreadsheet.getActiveRange()
    .sort([
      {column: 6, ascending: true}, 
      {column: 1, ascending: true}, 
      {column: 2, ascending: true}, 
      {column: 5, ascending: true}, 
      {column: 3, ascending: true}]);`
```

It sorts the columns, but uses only the exact values in the columns.  I need my sort script to reference a lookup value first.

The VLOOKUP formula converts the text of "frequency" to a number with a key-value pair.

| Frequency | Days |
| --- | --- |
| Daily | 0 |
| Weekly | 7 |
| Biweekly | 14 |
| Monthly | 30 |

The source rows have the word in the cell, but we need to sort by the numeric value rather than alphabetically.  The data rows are all text.  The sort formula uses column I, then D, then the numeric value from the VLOOPUP, then H, then finally column G.  The VLOOKP sorts to daily, weekly, biweekly, then monthly instead of biweekly, daily, monthly, then weekly alphabetically.  All other columns are just sorted alphabetically.

How would the formula be done using apps script?

Thanks for being awesome!

Comment: Can't you add an additional column in your source data sheet with that VLOOKUP result? Then you could use that column (let's say it's column 7 or 8) to apply the sorting code you already have

Comment: Not really.  The entire process is that I am filtering the original data in TabA, copying relevant rows, pasting those into TabB, refreshing the original data TabA, and then sorting TabA.  I've got everything working except the last sort step.  Adding a column just to cache the VLOOKUP result would confuse the user and make the automated copy more difficult.  Also, the sort should be re-run independently periodically through the day, hence the desire to have it as a script.

Comment: What I meant was a hidden column in TabA that would allow you to use the script you already have. Instead of sorting by `{column: 2, ascending: true}` you put `{column: 9, ascending: true}` (just an example, obviously, don't know your actual columns)

Comment: While that suggestion is technically a solution possibility, I would like to avoid adding columns and hopefully use a more elegant code-only solution.  The sheet has a large amount of scripting built on it and adding a column has a high possibility of messing up the existing legacy code.  If I added a column, it would take a large amount of testing to make sure the existing scripts still work and I would like to avoid that headache.

Comment: Hi and welcome. It seems to me that you have two questions: 1) convert an internal (`SORT`) formula to a function, and 2) sort a second range. It's really difficult to visualise this without knowing what the source data looks like, how the `VLOOKUP` works, and how a successful outcome (of both scenarios) would appear. There's also the risk of a sub-optimal answer because users can't foresee an outcome using other methods. Would you please edit your question to provide more information about your scenario, your data and the expected outcomes.

Comment: Ok, I've added more details above.  Does this help visualize what is going on?

Comment: @Tedinoz Typically, converting a sort formula to a function is straightforward, so that part is not the issue.  However, this sort involves a VLOOKUP, which is not typical (to my knowledge).  The app script functionality does not have an obvious equivalent to an embedded VLOOKUP that I am aware of, hence my question.  My searches could not return relevant results.  I suppose a rephrase of the question would be, "How would I embed an equivalent VLOOKUP formula in an app script sort function?"  I hope these clarifications illuminate the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a **SORT** problem. Your data includes a "Frequency" text field which does not sort reliably. So you have a table that matches each text values with a number of "Days" value.

Data on TabB is filtered and copied from raw data on TabA. You want to sort both TabA and TabB using the same sort logic.

- TabB can be sorted with an internal `SORT` function because the formula can be written to include `VLOOKUP` (finding the "days" value for the respective "Frequency")
- **BUT** Tab A cannot include the "Days" value, so sorting TabA data must be by script.

The following script takes the TabA data as an array:

- uses `indexOf` to add an element to the array for the "Days" value
- sorts the array according to a given column sequence (editable by the user)
- uses `pop to delete the "Days" element from the sorted array
- uses `setValues` to update the TabA data range with the sorted array.

---

```
function sortData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  // TabA contains raw data
  var tabA = ss.getSheetByName("TabA")
  var tabALR = tabA.getLastRow()
  
  // assume headers in row 1
  // assume 5 columns of data
  // assume "Frequency" is in Column D (Column 4)
  var tabARange = tabA.getRange(2,1,tabALR-1,5)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range = "+tabARange.getA1Notation())
  var tabAValues = tabARange.getValues()
  // Logger.log(tabAValues) // DEBUG

  // Sheet="Frequency" contains matching integer value for text values
  var freq = ss.getSheetByName("Frequency")
  // get the last row of Frequence data; assume that this sheet contains other data
  var Avals = freq.getRange("A1:A").getValues()
  var ALastRow = Avals.filter(String).length
  // note assumes header in row 1
  var freqValues = freq.getRange(2,1,ALastRow-1,2).getValues()
  // Logger.log(freqValues) // DEBUG

  // use indexOf to find the matching string value; the integer value will be in the adjacent column
  // assume the string "Frequency" is in Column D (zero-based= Column 3) of the data sheet
  // push the "Days" integer value onto the data array - this will be used for sorting
  for (var i=0;i<tabAValues.length;i++){
    var freqIdx = freqValues.map(r => r[0]).indexOf(tabAValues[i][3])
    var freqValue = freqValues[freqIdx][1]
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: freqIdx = "+freqIdx+", Frequency: "+tabAValues[i][3]+", number value = "+freqValues[freqIdx][1])
    // push the integer value onto the data array - this will be used for sorting
    tabAValues[i].push(freqValue)
  }

  // sort the array
  var sortSeq = [6,1,2,5,3]
  for (var s = 0;s<sortSeq.length;s++){}
    tabAValues.sort(function(x,y){
      var xp = x[s];
      var yp = y[s];
      return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;
    });
  

 // make a copy of the updated data array 
  var sortArray = new Array
  sortArray = tabAValues


  // delete the "Days" value from the array
  // returns the array 
  for (p=0;p<tabAValues.length;p++){
    sortArray[p].pop()
  }

  // update the data on TabA for the sorted values
  tabARange.setValues(sortArray)

}
```

---

**BEFORE**

[image: BEFORE]

**AFTER**

[image: after]